# How to disable color/appearance on indents [WebStorm]

Tags: colors, webstorm, disable, appearance

I have checked for hours online, I simply can not find an answer on how to disable the yellowish appearance on indents up to a character in a line. This is only for Vue.js projects and I have the plugin Vue automatically enabled.

How would you disable this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please place the caret where such a background is present and invoke Intentions/Quick Fix menu (`Alt+Enter` in most keymaps). Then show a screenshot of it. As far as I'm getting this it is NOT indents but another feature (that you have configured/enabled by mistake). P.S. As I understand this happens inside `<div>` tags only -- not in `<p>` or other block elements, right?

Comment: @LazyOne added new image. No its everywhere not just divs, also in scripts and such. Everywhere on every line till the first character in the line.

Comment: *"Expands shorthand property"* -- your 2nd screenshot does not look like it's a CSS file... Go to `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Language Injections`, sort by `Scope` column, descending. Then show ascreenshot of it -- interested in "Project" or "IDE" entries only.

Comment: @LazyOne Fixed! I clicked on the yellow line on the right side of the editor where it shows you an overview on which line you have 'issues' or errors. Basically 2nd screenshoot and go right on the arrow and disable the inspection. To anyone having same issue. Thanks man.

Comment: Well .. it's not what I originally though.... It's not caused by Language Injection.

Comment: It's a bit hard for me to judge because of the colors ... but still: 1) If you can make a screenshot using a standard light color scheme -- it may help. 2) In either case -- I now think it could be a Warning .. which may be caused by either incorrect indent symbol (TAB vs Space) or incorrect indent number (2 vs 4 spaces etc). You would need to check what inspection that is then.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! I clicked on the yellow line on the right side of the editor where it shows you an overview on which line you have 'issues' or errors. Basically 2nd screenshoot and go right on the arrow and disable the inspection. To anyone having same issue.

Comment: What was the inspection? Could be your ESLint integration. You may want to keep it and fix the actual issue (or your style rules) instead...